# How safe is virtual box without internet

Tags: virus, antimalware, python, virtual-memory

I am running a windows 7 virtual box without internet connected. Internet is, however, connected to the host, and I allow any internet access to and from the host. On the guest platform I am working with some sensitive documents that I do not want any viruses or attackers to get. Can someone look at the virtual box hard-drive stored in my host machine, and extract the information from the files there? If so, how can this be completely prevented. I am a Python programmer with massive experience in algorithms (no internet experience or networking), so I was wondering If I could create a program to block all internet access to a given file. This program would be able to completely deny *EVERYTHING* from the host that tries to access it; programs, internet, anything. I am not sure if that can be done though. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

In order to clarify the questions:

- How safe is virtual box when not connected to the internet?
- Can a listing of all internet access at a given time be obtained?
- How can everything be prevented from accessing the virtual box hard-drive, or anything related, where important data can be stored?
- If anyone knows any Python related security, how can this be implemented if at all?

P.S. I don't want a solution that encrypts the virtual hard drive so a point where I cannot use it. I want internet and foreign program access blocked, but still be able to use the guest virtual box machine from the host. Simply no outside access.

Comment: The guest is vulnerable to the host at all times so if the host has malware its not hard for it to pass on to the VM (The host has complete control over the VM but not vice-versa)

Answer (score 4):

Virtual machines work as sand boxes to keep bad things in, not bad things out.  If the host is compromised, so are the containers running within it as the virtual machine has to call out to the host for many actions and the host has full awareness and control over the system running within it.

Comment: Even if the VM is encrypted, a virus on the host could inspect its memory and get everything it needs